# vkCreateRenderPass returns invalid pointer

Tags: c++, vulkan

I am creating a render pass like so

```
const bool createRenderPass() {
 VkAttachmentDescription colorAttachment{};
 colorAttachment.format = swapChainImageFormat;
 colorAttachment.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
 colorAttachment.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
 colorAttachment.storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
 colorAttachment.stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
 colorAttachment.stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
 colorAttachment.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
 colorAttachment.finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR;
 VkAttachmentReference colorAttachmentRef{};
 colorAttachmentRef.attachment = 0;
 colorAttachmentRef.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;
 VkSubpassDescription subpass{};
 subpass.pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
 subpass.colorAttachmentCount = 1;
 subpass.pColorAttachments = &colorAttachmentRef;
 VkSubpassDependency dependency{};
 dependency.srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
 dependency.dstSubpass = 0;
 dependency.srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
 dependency.srcAccessMask = 0;
 dependency.dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
 dependency.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
 VkRenderPassCreateInfo renderPassInfo{};
 renderPassInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_CREATE_INFO;
 renderPassInfo.attachmentCount = 1;
 renderPassInfo.pAttachments = &colorAttachment;
 renderPassInfo.subpassCount = 1;
 renderPassInfo.pSubpasses = &subpass;
 renderPassInfo.dependencyCount = 1;
 renderPassInfo.pDependencies = &dependency;
 if (vkCreateRenderPass(device, &renderPassInfo, nullptr, &renderPass) != VK_SUCCESS) {
  printf("%s\n\r", "failed to create render pass!");
  return false;
 }
 return true;
};
```

However when I run it `renderPass` **results in an invalid pointer**: `0xe000000000e`

Up to this stage, each stage of the render pipeline, (i.e, instance/device/swapchain/imageview creation) has been valid. So what is going wrong with the renderPass?

Comment: What is the debug layer telling you? What is the return code of `vkCreateRenderPass`?

Comment: `VK_SUCCESS` & the debug layer reports nothing

Comment: "*each stage of the render pipeline has been valid*" What 'render pipeline'? Render passes don't have 'render pipelines'.

Comment: updated question to clarify that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However when I run it renderPass results in an invalid pointer: 0xe000000000e

There are two types of handle returned by Vulkan functions:

- dispatchable:

> *Dispatchable handle* types are a pointer to an opaque type. This pointer may be used by layers as part of intercepting API commands, and thus each API command takes a dispatchable type as its first parameter.

- non-distpatchable:

> *Non-dispatchable handle* types are a 64-bit integer type whose meaning is implementation-dependent.

`VkRenderPass` is [defined](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Headers/blob/3be1df310be8963c29125c35fce25ee0af12ff70/include/vulkan/vulkan_core.h#L116) as a non-distpatchable handle.  There's no reason to look at the value and consider it as anything other than a 64 bit value.  Whether or not it's a valid memory pointer is completely irrelevant.

You say in the comments that the function returns `VK_SUCCESS` and the validation layers don't report anything wrong.  So what is the problem?  If you're still having a problem rendering, it's likely not the render pass object, but something else.

Comment: okay, so `VkRenderPass` may be a usable handle. However now I'm getting validation errors for `vkDestroyPipeline` & `vkDestroyPipelineLayout`, both due to `Invalid Objects`. Should I ask I new question concerning them aswell?

Comment: Yes that sounds like a new question. But you should also mark Jherico's answer as correct.